# Work with GitHub Multiple Accounts

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have followed the [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-work-with-github-and-multiple-accounts--net-22574) to set SSH key for multiple github accounts.

But I keep getting the error

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github-psdtowordpresspro.com: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Steps followed:

1. Created SSH key: `id_rsa_psdtowordpresspro.pub` file in `.ssh` directory. (Note that this folder was not there earlier. so I had to create one)

Used the syntax `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your-email-address"`

2. Added the SSH key to my 2nd github account
3. Added the key

   ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_COMPANY
4. Created the `.config` file with the command

   touch ~/.ssh/config
   vim config

This is the code I wrote in my `.config` file

```
Host github-regipheirim
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_psdtowordpresspro
```

which is exactly how it was mentioned in the tutorial.

Then I added the remote origin as

```
git remote add origin git@github-psdtowordpresspro.com:regipheirim/regi.git
```

But then when I try to push it shows the error that "Hostname could not be resolved."

Here is a screenshot of

[Git remote connection setting of second account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QWvT.png)

Project's `.config` file

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github-regipheirim:regipheirim/regi.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[user]
    name = regipheirim
    email = p.regidev@gmail.com
```

**ALSO TRIED (Based on suggestion from TJL in comment section)**

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:regipheirim/regi.git
```

But then when I tried to push with

```
git push origin master
```

Again I get the error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

So can anyone help me with what I am doing wrong here. I just spent the entire sunday figuring it out.

Comment: GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv"

Answer (score 1):

You did not link to alias you have created in your config file

try:

`git remote add origin git@github-regipheirim:regipheirim/regi.git`

Comment: Thanks a lot @TLJ. I was doing a really silly mistake the whole day, instead of regipheirim I was using my company name... So silly. Now it did push to the repo. But strange it did push from my first main account. May I know why? I mean it should be pusing from the second account right?

FYI: I am using `git push origin master` as the command to push

Comment: I would use `git remote -v` to list out what have been set. Maybe `origin` is set to `@github.com` instead of  `regipheirim` alias? let me know

Comment: `origin  git@github-regipheirim:regipheirim/regi.git (fetch)
origin  git@github-regipheirim:regipheirim/regi.git (push)
`
This is what gir remote -v returns

Comment: Tried deleting the repo. And repeat the entire process with your suggestion. But still it did push from the main account. Strange

Comment: Check current email account using `git config user.email`. I suspect it is your main account. If so set it to your 2nd account. using `git config user.email = {youremail}`

Comment: @RegiPheirim I'm just curious. Did you get this going?

Comment: Thanks a lot. But no still the commit is happening from my primary account. An yes I have tried setting user name and email earlier too. but no help. I still don't get it.. why is it pushing from main account

Answer (score 0):

Solution for multiple accounts from that same service. In this case for Bitbucket.

## 1) Open `~/.gitconfig` file

## 2) Add section for each of the accounts

For example for user `JohnDoe` (with rsa key in `~/.ssh/id_rsa_john_1`) you should add

```
Host bitbucket.org:JohnDoe
 User JohnDoe
 HostName bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_john_1
 IdentitiesOnly yes
```

this username should also exist in URL which you are trying to clone via SSH, for example:

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:JohnDoe/my_project.git
```

---

And when you have different account in that same service you can add it also:

```
Host bitbucket.org:RichardRoe
 User RichardRoe
 HostName bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_richard_1
 IdentitiesOnly yes
```

So in your file you will have TWO sections about `bitbucket.org`.

Thanks to that you can use separate accounts (with different RSA keys).

## 3) Run `eval $(ssh-agent)`

## 4) Use `ssh-add` for all of the accounts

So for this example it will be:

```
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa_john_1
```

and

```
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa_richard_1
```